# OMA: LwM2M server architecture and resources?

Tags: eclipse, iot, m2m, oma, lwm2m

I am a bit confused about the LwM2M server, I can't find the resources that it contains.

On the specifications I only found descriptions about the LwM2M client and the resources that it can contain but I found nothing on the server side besides the interfaces that it shall support.
(I mean it should somewhere store the list of the registered client for example..)

Any ideas where I can find information about the LwM2M server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LWM2M server doesn't contain resources, the device register on it and then it's up to the server user to manipulate the device resources for performing tasks like firmware upgrade or reading the configuration.
Does it make sense?

Comment: I see, so the server does not contains the resources but he has some knowledge about the kind of resources available in the client, right? since in the registration interface, the client end point and the client supported objects and object instances are required. Am I right? Thanks